# Are there any Iyun Tefilla lectures online or in-house in Nassau County, Brooklyn or Queens?

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, adult-learning

I think the question title pretty much states everything.

I'm seeking a live shiur (lecture) that focuses on *iyun tefilla* - understanding the prayers. Preferably, I would like the class to discuss things from a somewhat "introductory" level focusing on the history of prayer, overall, how it evolved, how and why it eventually became congregational, and when / why it moved to a *Bet Knesset*. I'd also like it to focus on a selected prayer service (e.g. Shacharit weekday, etc.)

I have been reading Steinzaltz intro book on prayer and it is quite good. But, I'd prefer a live discussion either in person or online (Skype, etc.) I haven't been able to locate either. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: My own related question - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82022/5275

Comment: I (not Chasidic) just signed up to "The Heart of Prayer" from Chabad online. First lecture was good.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to consider the online course from Chabad ["The Heart of Prayer"](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/course_cdo/aid/3869186/jewish/The-Heart-of-Prayer.htm).

The first lecture was good and did not involve any problems of nusach. There are stored recordings and a Facebook page where comments and questions can be left for the lecturer.

This is the summary "About the Course" - the syllabus is at the website.

> Prayer can be one of the most confounding of spiritual practices. If
>   it is a personal, meditative, soul experience, then why is so much of
>   it dictated by formality and structured liturgy? If we are praying to
>   an all-knowing higher power, then why do we need to express thoughts,
>   feelings and needs that are already revealed? It turns out that prayer
>   is about developing a relationship. And just like any intimate
>   relationship, it is full of nuances and subtleties; there is both an
>   art and a science to prayer.